# How determine most recent active local windows user accounts?

Tags: windows, windows-10, user-accounts, user-profiles

We have a few computers that many employees (70+) have used over the years. 
I am upgrading these and want to transfer the most recent users. Just the ones that have signed into the system in the last 3 months.

Looking at the users folder and using modified dates is inaccurate, some are off by a year even if a user signed in yesterday.

AD only tells me the last user.

How can I determine the most recent signed in users?

Answer (score 0):

If you have it enabled: on event viewer in the security protocoll, keyword Audit Success, category logon, ID 4624...

[image]

[image]

You can enable it using Local Group Policy Editor -> Computer Configuration -> Windows Settings -> Security Settings -> Local Policies -> Audit Policy. You need to enable "Audit logon events".

I like a batch readout via powershell that can show me a table, like [this one](https://docs.microsoft.com/de-de/previous-versions//ee176846(v=technet.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN).

Alternatively you could use a cmd script that starts up on each login:

```
::Optional
@echo off

::Checks for folder and creats it if it doesnt exist
if not exist c:\Logs md c:\Logs

::checks the userinfo and writes it into the log file including time stamp
echo Logon: %date% %time:~0,5% %UserName% >> c:\Logs\History.txt
```

Or you could use a third party tool, e.g. [this one](https://www.creative-tools.de/software/windows-anmeldezeiten-von-benutzern-auslesen/)

Comment: Gave that a shot, however my logs only go back 6 days.

Comment: I don't think there is another log, you could enable it, or use a script of you own to capture future logons (see update)